# Excel vba : Synchronize two drop down lists in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm starting to use Excel VBA to create drop down lists using data validation but i would like to synchronize  two drop down lists in the same worksheet.
I created the first list which is 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and I created the second list which is A, B, C, D, E

My purpose is when I choose Item number 3 from the first list (which is 3) automatically the Item number 3 (which is C) from the second list will be displayed.

I tried to use the INDEX and MATCH fct but without success could you please help me with that

Thank you for your help 
Hichem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a data validation drop-down in a cell, you shouldn't have a formula in that cell at the same time. As a rule, a cell should either be calculated or used for data entry, not both.

Using a formula, you can put the values you want to calculate in the second cell into the spreadsheet somewhere, if they are not already. Then you can use a simple Vlookup or Index/Match.  For example, all drop-down list options are stored on a sheet called Setup. The values for the second data validation list are in the cells C2 to C6. The values for the first data validation list are in cells A2 to A6. You can now use the value selected in the data validation list like this:

```
=index(Setup!$C$2:$C$6,match(Sheet1!C2,Setup!$A$2:$A$6,0))
```

In words: in column A of the setup sheet, find the value that is the same as C2 in Sheet1 and return the value from column C of the setup sheet in the same row.

Comment: Thank you Teylyn for your answer.
Sorry I couldn't understand your answer. may be I didn't explained good my problem. 
I would like to link tow drop down validation list. when I choose the first item of the first  drop down validation list automatically the first item will be displayed on the second drop down validation list
here an exmple
let's say that I have 2 drop down validation lists
the first contains 1,2,3 and 4 and the second contains A,B,C and D
So when I choose 2 from the first drop down validation list automatically i will choose B in the second drop down validation list

Comment: Maybe this forum for advanced programmers is not the right place for your question. If you have Excel experience, Vlookup or Index/Match formulas should not be too hard to understand. You cannot synchronise  data validation lists like you describe. To achieve something like that you either need VBA code or formulas. I've shown the formula approach with sheet names, ranges and the exact formula you need. What aspect do you need more help with?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I used the function index with match and it works properly.
You method works for a limited number of dropdown lists but in my case I have more then 50 dropdown lists to synchronize so manually it will takes time.
My question is is there any way to make it automatic, now I'm trying to create a function using index and match with iterative manner, and this function will be called in a main program whenever it detect a change of selection in one of the list. It means when select something from the first list this action will lunch a macro that will call my function

Comment: My formula works for an unlimited number. You can use it for one, two or fifty lookups. Seems to me that your data architecture is not supporting what you want to achieve. You may want to re-think your approach overall. Why would you have 50 dropdown lists??? You need to step back from that approach and explain the bigger picture. But not here. Start a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I solved my problem, I used dependent combo box instead of validation lists and the synchronization works perfectly for me.

Comment: I fail to see how dependent data validation solves the issue you describe in your question, which leads me to believe that you did not describe the actual issue.

Comment: Like I mentioned I used combo box not a data validation list. 
For each combo, right-click and select View Code.
Make the Change event procedures look like:

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With ComboBox1
    ComboBox2.ListIndex = .ListIndex
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  With ComboBox2
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = .ListIndex
  End With
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub